# How to fix error messages for anroid studio

Tags: android-studio

i'm newby here and also not so good with technology. Tried to set up anrdoid studio, but something went wrong and I uninstalled the app. at the second and third time of the reinstalling, i'm getting the next messsage and i really don't know what to do:

Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

```
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$EssentialPluginMissingException: Missing essential plugins: com.android.tools.design, org.jetbrains.android
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.checkEssentialPluginsAreAvailable(PluginManagerCore.java:761)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:854)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializeAndSetPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1068)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader$scheduleLoading$pluginSetDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(PluginDescriptorLoader.kt:397)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr
```

Please, I'm looking someone who can help me and explain me step by step what i have to do to fix it.
thanks in advance
Maria

unistalled and reinstalled but didn't worked.